# Issues with unit testing

Tags: python, testing, encoding, monte-carlo-tree-search

I want to test a function, but I am definitely struggling at this one. The function loops through boards last row if NO_PLayer is valid location.

```
def validLocations(board):

    validLocationsArr = []

    column = 0
    row = 0
    while column < 6:

        if (board[5][column] == NO_PLAYER):
                validLocationsArr.append(column)

        column += 1

    return validLocationsArr
```

I worked on it, and tried it, but:

```
def test_validLocations(self):
    from agents.common import validLocations

    ret = validLocations(board)
    assert np.all(ret == NO_PLAYER)
```

Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide what value `board` is in the test function. And what is `NO_PLAYER` set to? `object()`?

Answer (score 0):

Wihout further info from the OP, I think the problem is in the last `assert` statement.

Use [Python's `all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead of Numpy's `np.all()`:

```py
ret = validLocations(board)  # as before
assert all(loc == NO_PLAYER for loc in ret)
```